Second derivative of vector valued function expressed in terms of its vector constitutes.
I'm working on a backstepping controller, one of my virtual controls is $\alpha_q$, to implement the final controller I need its first and second derivatives, $\dot{\alpha}$ and $\ddot{\alpha}$.
\begin{equation}
\alpha_q=\left[
\begin{aligned}
&\arctan \left(\frac{\cos \left(\psi_d (t) \right) \Omega_1(t)+\sin \left(\psi_d (t)\right) \Omega_2(t)}{\Omega_3(t)}\right)\\
&\arcsin \left(\frac{\sin \left(\psi_d (t)\right) \Omega_1(t)-\cos \left(\psi_d (t)\right) \Omega_2(t)}{\sqrt{\boldsymbol{\Omega} (t)^T \boldsymbol{\Omega}(t)}}\right)\\
&\quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad \quad\psi_d (t)
\end{aligned}\right]
\end{equation}
where $\Omega$ is a $3\times1$ vector:
\begin{equation}
\boldsymbol{\Omega} (t)=m(g\boldsymbol{e}_{3}-\eta_{e} (t)-\dot{\boldsymbol{\eta}}_{e} (t) +\ddot{\boldsymbol{\eta}}_{d} (t)-\boldsymbol{v}_e (t))
\end{equation}.
What I've done is use the chain rule:
\begin{equation}
    \frac{d \boldsymbol{\alpha}_q}{dt}=\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{\alpha}_q}{\partial \boldsymbol{\Omega}} \frac{d \boldsymbol{\Omega}}{dt}+\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{\alpha}}{\partial \psi_d}\dot{\psi_d}
\end{equation}
and where,
\begin{equation}
\begin{aligned}
\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{\alpha}_q}{\partial \boldsymbol{\Omega}} = \left[
\begin{array}{c}
\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{\alpha}_1}{\partial \Omega_1} + \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{\alpha}_1}{\partial \Omega_2} + \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{\alpha}_1}{\partial \Omega_3} \\
\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{\alpha}_2}{\partial \Omega_1} + \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{\alpha}_2}{\partial \Omega_2} + \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{\alpha}_2}{\partial \Omega_3} \\
\frac{\partial \boldsymbol{\alpha}_3}{\partial \Omega_1} + \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{\alpha}_3}{\partial \Omega_2} + \frac{\partial \boldsymbol{\alpha}_3}{\partial \Omega_3}
\end{array}
\right]
\end{aligned}
\end{equation}
However, I am not sure this is correct and am even less sure of my second derivative attempt as my simulated controller didn't work.

You got it kind of wrong. I'd suggest you refer to this question of mine about the second derivative and its chain rule. Basically, the first derivative would be
$$\dfrac{\mathrm d\boldsymbol\alpha_q}{\mathrm dt}=\dfrac{\partial\boldsymbol\alpha_q}{\partial\boldsymbol\Omega}\dfrac{\mathrm d\boldsymbol\Omega}{\mathrm d t}+\dfrac{\partial\boldsymbol\alpha_q}{\partial\psi_d}\dfrac{\mathrm d\psi_d}{\mathrm dt}$$
where $\dfrac{\partial\boldsymbol\alpha_q}{\partial\boldsymbol\Omega}$ is a $3\times 3$ matrix with components $\dfrac{\partial(\boldsymbol\alpha_q)_i}{\partial\Omega_j}$. Looks like there's no explicit expression in $t$ so I assumed $\partial_t\boldsymbol\alpha_q=0$.
As for the second derivative, you can apply distributivity and product rule for the temporal differential operator:
$$\dfrac{\mathrm d^2\boldsymbol\alpha_q}{\mathrm dt^2}=\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\left(\dfrac{\partial\boldsymbol\alpha_q}{\partial\boldsymbol\Omega}\right)\dfrac{\mathrm d\boldsymbol\Omega}{\mathrm d t}+\dfrac{\partial\boldsymbol\alpha_q}{\partial\boldsymbol\Omega}\dfrac{\mathrm d^2\boldsymbol\Omega}{\mathrm d t^2}+\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\left(\dfrac{\partial\boldsymbol\alpha_q}{\partial\psi_d}\right)\dfrac{\mathrm d\psi_d}{\mathrm dt}+\dfrac{\partial\boldsymbol\alpha_q}{\partial\psi_d}\dfrac{\mathrm d^2\psi_d}{\mathrm dt^2}$$
where
$$\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\left(\dfrac{\partial\boldsymbol\alpha_q}{\partial\boldsymbol\Omega}\right)=\dfrac{\partial^2\boldsymbol\alpha_q}{\partial\boldsymbol\Omega\partial\boldsymbol\Omega}\dfrac{\mathrm d\boldsymbol\Omega}{\mathrm d t}+\dfrac{\partial^2\boldsymbol\alpha_q}{\partial\psi_d\partial\boldsymbol\Omega}\dfrac{\mathrm d\psi_d}{\mathrm d t}$$
and where
$$\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\left(\dfrac{\partial\boldsymbol\alpha_q}{\partial\psi_d}\right)=\dfrac{\partial^2\boldsymbol\alpha_q}{\partial\boldsymbol\Omega\partial\psi_d}\dfrac{\mathrm d\boldsymbol\Omega}{\mathrm dt}+\dfrac{\partial^2\boldsymbol\alpha_q}{\partial\psi_d^2}\dfrac{\mathrm d\psi_d}{\mathrm d t}.$$
Note that $\dfrac{\partial^2\boldsymbol\alpha_q}{\partial\boldsymbol\Omega\partial\boldsymbol\Omega}$ is a $3\times 3\times 3$ tensor and it satisfies
$$\dfrac{\partial^2\boldsymbol\alpha_q}{\partial\boldsymbol\Omega\partial\boldsymbol\Omega}\dfrac{\mathrm d\boldsymbol\Omega}{\mathrm d t}=
\begin{pmatrix}
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol\Omega}\left(\dfrac{\partial(\boldsymbol\alpha_q)_1}{\partial\Omega_1}\right)\dot{\boldsymbol\Omega} & \dfrac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol\Omega}\left(\dfrac{\partial(\boldsymbol\alpha_q)_1}{\partial\Omega_2}\right)\dot{\boldsymbol\Omega} & \dfrac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol\Omega}\left(\dfrac{\partial(\boldsymbol\alpha_q)_1}{\partial\Omega_3}\right)\dot{\boldsymbol\Omega}\\
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol\Omega}\left(\dfrac{\partial(\boldsymbol\alpha_q)_2}{\partial\Omega_1}\right)\dot{\boldsymbol\Omega} & \dfrac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol\Omega}\left(\dfrac{\partial(\boldsymbol\alpha_q)_2}{\partial\Omega_2}\right)\dot{\boldsymbol\Omega} & \dfrac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol\Omega}\left(\dfrac{\partial(\boldsymbol\alpha_q)_2}{\partial\Omega_3}\right)\dot{\boldsymbol\Omega}\\
\dfrac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol\Omega}\left(\dfrac{\partial(\boldsymbol\alpha_q)_3}{\partial\Omega_1}\right)\dot{\boldsymbol\Omega} & \dfrac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol\Omega}\left(\dfrac{\partial(\boldsymbol\alpha_q)_3}{\partial\Omega_2}\right)\dot{\boldsymbol\Omega} & \dfrac{\partial}{\partial\boldsymbol\Omega}\left(\dfrac{\partial(\boldsymbol\alpha_q)_3}{\partial\Omega_3}\right)\dot{\boldsymbol\Omega}
\end{pmatrix}$$

Thanks for the response. You wouldn't know if there's a simple way to implement all these derivatives in matlab, or should I manually create the tensors and partial derivative terms?

I have never used MatLab. Maybe you should ask it elsewhere or manually create them.
